# Windows 10 Powershell running Docker with multi-line command get error

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-10

Under Windows 10, from PowerShell, I try to run:

```
PS C:\temp> docker run --name postgres_test `
>>     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword `
>>     -p "5432:5432" `
>>     -d postgres
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\temp>
```

which fails, as shown above, with the error message:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid
>   reference format.

If I remove the line continuation and just run

```
PS C:\temp> docker run --name postgres_test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword  -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

It runs fine.

Am I messing up the line continuation somehow?

Comment: The error message suggests that something other than `postgres` was interpreted as the image name, but the commands you're showing should be equivalent (you're not double-quoting `5432:5432` in the single-line version, but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference).

Comment: Not reproduce on my side, I guess some information was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I found non-printable characters in the command line.  Once removed, it worked.